# How to use Javascript Core (JSC) on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to run a JSC (https://github.com/facebook/android-jsc) on an Android app. I can't find any API to use it with. Can you guide me to any resource?

Answer (score 0):

Using gradle

```
implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650'
```

But if you download `aar` file e.g. http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/webkit/android-jsc/r174650/android-jsc-r174650.aar Then `classes.jar` will be empty in it. There are avaliable only jni binaries